# VB.net Get Access to the path ... is denied when run in a thread (only in production)

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, access-denied

I have an web form app that does a xslt transformation.

If I call the method normally everything runs fine like so:

```
SendReceiptEmail(infoObject) 'runs fine, no exceptions thrown
```

But if I try to call the same method in a THREAD it throws the Access is denied Exception but only on the production server, on my development and test servers everything is fine:

```
Dim newThread As New Threading.Thread(SendReceiptEmail)
newThread.Start(infoObject)
```

The method looks like this:

```
Public Shared Function SendReceiptEmail(ByVal infoObject As MyObject ) As Boolean
Try
  Dim fromAddr As String = infoObject.fromEmail
  Dim toAddrAs String = infoObject.toEmail
  Dim subject As String = infoObject.subject
  Dim body As String = BuildCustomerReceipt(infoObject ) '!!! <== exception thown only if run in a thread in Production
  Dim m As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(fromAddr, toAddr, subject, body)
  return True
....
  Catch ex As Exception
    'The ex.Message caught here is "Access to the path <full paath & name of xslt> is denied - only get it when run as a thread in Production
    Return False 
  End Try
  Return True
End Function
```

The BuildCustomerReceipt function, which passes the exception, looks like this:

```
Public Shared Function BuildCustomerReceipt( infoObject ) As String
  Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
  ...build doc ...
  Dim pathToXslTemplate As String = "<FUll path to xslt file>" 
  Dim emailBody As String = XslTransform(doc, pathToXslTemplate) ' <== exception from here!
  Return emailBody
End Function
```

And finally the method that actually throws the Exception is like so:

```
Public Shared Function XslTransform(ByVal doc As XmlDocument, ByVal pathToXslTemplate As String) As String
  Dim objXSLTransform As XslCompiledTransform = New XslCompiledTransform()

  objXSLTransform.Load(pathToXslTemplate) ' !!! <== Exception Thrown from here  !!!

  Dim objSWriter As New StringWriter()
  objXSLTransform.Transform(doc, Nothing, objSWriter)
  Return objSWriter.ToString()

End Function
```

It looks like a file permission issue, but I don't know why it occurs or how to fix it.  The same application runs both the threaded and non-threaded versions, so why does the threaded version not have the same access as it's parent application?

BTW - Development is Windows 7 but Production is Windows Server 2008 and the IDE is Visual Studio 2008

Comment: A work around that I am using is this. - (Ugg this comment xox dosn't allow new lines! )  - I loaded the xslt file into a global string when tha app started, then my thread did the xslt trasform from the global sting instead of trying to read the file.  ---------------   would still love to see a solution or explanation as to WHY the thread didn't have same access as its parent application.

Comment: Hi Paul, (5 years later...) Did you managed to understand the root cause? (I encountered it myself today...)